# Selecting several different ranges with df.iloc?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I need to select the 1. and the 4-15. row in an excel dataframe with df.iloc, but I just can't get the correct syntax, now I'm not even sure if its possible to do?
I tried: df.iloc[1,4:15:,:] and df.iloc[1:4:15:,:], I also tried to input the variables as a list of: [1,4,5....15] but neither work, could anyone help with the syntax of this?
Found nothing on google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using slice AND list of integers in pandas iloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420715/using-slice-and-list-of-integers-in-pandas-iloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine list and slices with numpy's [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
df = df.iloc[np.r_[1,4:15], :]
```

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [[ 1  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]] of <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: I accidently had as cols not rows. Should be fixed now. Just tried on random data and it works.

Comment: Yeah, It's fine, but  I did change it myself to rows when I got the error